# how to ask for privacy list - xmpp titanium

Tags: xmpp, titanium, appcelerator, quickblox, appcelerator-alloy

I would like to ask for the [privacy list](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0016.html) of a user connected to the xmpp server (in my case using [quickblox](http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Connecting_to_server)). I'm using titanium and [this](https://github.com/jmartin82/titanium-xmpp/tree/master/Resources) library.

This is the alloy code to send a message from the app to the server

```
Alloy.Globals.xmpp = require("JXMPP");
Alloy.Globals.xmppConn = new Alloy.Globals.xmpp.Connection();
Alloy.Globals.xmppMsg = function(u,m){
    var oMsg = new Alloy.Globals.xmpp.Packet.Message();
    oMsg.setTo(new Alloy.Globals.xmpp.JID( u+"-app_id@chat.quickblox.com"));
    oMsg.setBody();
    Alloy.Globals.xmppConn.send(m);

};
```

and from the controller

```
Alloy.Globals.xmppMsg(user,"<iq from='"+user+"-26905@chat.quickblox.com' type='get' id='getlist1'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'><list name='public'/></query></iq>");
```

the output display the follows (as [Ti.API.info](https://github.com/jmartin82/titanium-xmpp/blob/master/Resources/xmpp/JXMPPConnection.js#L456) from the library says)

```
no packet: <iq from='x-y@chat.quickblox.com' type='get' id='getlist1'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'><list name='public'/></query></iq>
```

How to prepare the request for the privacy list?

Comment: Did you try asking the author of the library you use? https://github.com/jmartin82/titanium-xmpp/issues